# Skip validation on dependent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having a User and a Company model like below. Company model has some validations.

**user.rb**

```
    after_create :create_tables!

    def create_tables!
      companies.create!(handle: "random_handle")
   end
```

**company.rb**

```
before_destroy :check_for_presence_of_a_company!

def check_for_presence_of_a_company!
  if user.companies.count <= 1
    errors.add(:base, 'You cannot delete all of your companies.')
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

when user creates account for the first time i create a company for him using **after_create** in User model and before deleting a company he should have atleast one company.

But the problem is when user tries to delete his account, the above company validations throws error.

When user deletes his account, it should neglect the above validation **company.rb**. How can i achieve this? Thanks.

***Edit***

In *user.rb* i updated

```
has_many :companies,dependent: :destroy
```

to

```
has_many :companies,dependent: :delete_all
```

But *company.rb*

```
has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
```

and shows *violates foreign key constraint* error. Updating it from destroy to delete_all is also not working.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you have this (although you didn't show it):

```
class User
  has_many :companies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If so, you can change `:destroy` to `:delete_all`:

```
has_many :companies, dependent: :delete_all
```

Per https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many:

> `:delete_all` causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not be executed).

(n.b. since callbacks on `Company` won't be run, if you need additional associations to be deleted, you'd have to handle those separately.)

Comment: That solves half the problem. Updating it in question.

Comment: How can i handle those seperately? after_delete is not available. after_destroy isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `dependent: :destroy` you can add a `after_destroy` callback and call `delete` or `delete_all` (which doesn't run validations).

```
# user.rb

after_destroy :delete_companies

def delete_companies
  companies.delete_all
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question and still there is dependency problem. Can you answer please?